# Can we run commands in terminal directly from scite editor?

Tags: c++, text-editor, scite

I just started using Scite Text editor.

Is it possible to change our directory location and run the commands in terminal directly from scite  ?

Is there any other text editor for c/c++ which can support this ?

Comment: Try [qt creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Comment: It is possible to run terminal commands from scite. Just open output pane (F8) and type command. But changing directory I think is impossible and reserved for current folder of the file in opened buffer, if any.